# Navigation Drawer in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Anyone know how to make a navigation drawer in the Unity3D or is that even possible. 
I have tried googling for answers but I can't find any so I guess it ain't possible, so the last hope I have is to ask.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: What's navigation drawer?

Comment: oh, you mean the side menu? in unity3d I would use panel, with scrollview and move it right/left on click/touch detection. Maybe use some tween engine to move it smoothly :)

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka sorry I hadn't been able to go online.., but yeah it's the side menu.. Thanks for the answer now I have an idea how to do one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extremely easy.  Just use the UI system.

1, click add canvas (note: **always** choose "scale to screen size")

2, click add panel.  also try add button, etc

3, add a UI "scroll view" and learn how to use it.

you can now very easily make UX elements such as drawers, pullouts etc

incredibly easy, full tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcU8yzv_xEw